# findstr for executing a command if str does not contain 169

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, findstr, errorlevel

I am new to batch files and have seen several posts about findstr but could not get it to find a 169 inside a string which contains an IP address

```
    set Foo=169.254.100.1
    SET Foo|findstr /i 169
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo it doesnt contain 169, do launch) else (echo it contains 169, don't do launch)
```

)

Foo contains 169 as you can see, but when I do findstr, it returns 1 and shows "it doesnt contain 169, do launch"

Could anybody see what is wrong here?

Comment: I have no idea how it is not working for you. The code you posted works for me. The `/i` switch is not needed, but it doesn't do any harm either.

Comment: May I suggest to use `echo %foo%|findstr 169` instead of `set foo|findstr 169`? You may have another variable that starts with `foo`, like "foobar" and you may get "wrong positives". Asides this, your code works good for me.

Comment: Another thing: use `/B` with `findstr` (search at the beginning of the string), otherwise `10.11.12.169` will be positive too (not, what you want, I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest another way to achieve this test that does *not* use findstr?

```
set Foo=169.254.100.1
if "%Foo:169=%" equ "%Foo%" (
   echo it doesnt contain 169, do launch
) else (
   echo it contains 169, don't do launch
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. It seems to work for me. The only thing I realized that for some reason,  on my machine we need to write ! instead of %. After replacing those, I get the proper behavior.